# Do skills carry over with levels?

Tags: the-witcher-3

For example, if I acquire the level-2 skill on the light/fast attack 'tree' and activate it (by placing it in a 'slot'), does the level-1 skill too get activated by default or do I have to equip it in another 'slot' for it to be active?

So basically, does activating a skill in a skill tree activate all other skills above it by default, or do they have to be placed in separate slots?

Comment: When you mean lower down, do you mean the tiers of the skill tree, or the previous levels of the same skill?

Comment: I believe he means "skills that are directly above the newly purchased skill". i.e. "Does Precise Blows (swordsmanship, light, #2) include the benefits from Muscle Memory (swordsmanship, light, #1)".

Comment: @Jeeva Yes that's exactly what I mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to equip skills in slots to have them active, lower level or not.

Comment: Are you sure? Cause there's only 12 slots and what, 85(?) skills, so that would drastically limit my options

Comment: Yes. You can test this, if you wish, by (saving first if you don't want the skill long-term, and) equipping a skill such as `Survival Instinct` (+500 Vitality), and removing it. You should be able to see your max vitality jumping. Alternatively, you could toggle `Muscle Memory`, and check the character stat sheet (`'C'`, on PC). You should be able to see Light Attack damage changing.

Comment: Additionally, I would say that you might be surprised at how over-powered a few decent skills will make you in combination.

Comment: Additionally (#2), As opening up the list of active skills stops time.  You can change out your current skills and mutagens on the fly.  This can be stupidly overpowered.

Answer (score 1):

Each icon is a separate skill that needs to be put in slot to be active. Everything outside the skill slot is not active.